# Is there a kind of microdata or markup that creates "results x of y" in search results

Tags: microdata, rich-snippets

I'm trying to get the following kind of markup appear on my job site:

[image]

There's a [specific markup](http://schema.org/JobPosting) for job adverts listed on the schema.org webpage, but I can't work out how Google is pulling the 1 - 20 of 23229 from the Monster webpage.

I'm presuming the jobs tag is because they use microdata markup for all their adverts, but how is Google pulling the numbers?

There is a specific page tag for search results ([here](http://schema.org/SearchResultsPage)), however it doesn't seem to have any relevant options and as far as I can tell Monster aren't using it anyway.

(A search for monster jobs china should show the result)

Comment: It may just have to do with pagination

Comment: To follow Johns remark, it may be a literal count of the mark-ups found by Google assuming one per job page.

Comment: @JohnConde Hmm I'll try putting on the job advert markup and pagination next and prev takes and report back!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are cheating. There's a hidden `<span>` near the top the page with the following content:

```
<span style="display: none;"> Jobs 1 to 20 of 24066</span>
```

I'm not sure what your exact search was, but it looks like Google's snippet generator isn't finding much relevant on the page to use a snippet, so it's using the first piece of "proper" (non-navigation, non-header) content in the mark-up, and the meta description to try and make something useful for you.

```
<meta name="description" content="Search for China jobs at Monster. Browse our collection of China job listings, including openings in full time and part time." />
```

Comment: Clever, I've not yet managed to get this to work on my site. So perhaps there is another sort of inbuilt reputation factor before it'll do this.